# Passing primitive pointers to C function from Cython

Tags: python, c, cython

I am writing a Cython wrapper around a C library we are maintaining.  I am getting the following error message:

```
analog.pyx:6:66: Cannot convert 'unsigned short (*)' to Python object
```

Here's the code I am trying to write:

```python
cimport company as lib

def get_value(device, channel, index):
    cdef unsigned short aValue

    err = library_get_data_val(device, channel, index, &aValue) # line 6

    # Ignore the err return value for StackOverflow.

    return aValue
```

The prototype of the C function I am trying to use is:

```python
unsigned long library_get_data_val(unsigned long device, int channel,
    int index, unsigned short *pValue);
```

The library function returns the requested value in the `aValue` parameter.  It's just an `unsigned short` primitive.  What's the expected way of returning primitives (i.e. not `struct`) from these type of functions?  I am new to Cython so the answer may be quite simple but I didn't see anything obvious through Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what my problem was.  You can probably tell what it is now that I've edited the question.  There's a `company.pxd` file that's `cimport`ed by the `.pyx` file.  Once I copied the C prototype into `company.pxd` it worked.

I also needed to use the `lib` prefix in my call:

```python
err = lib.library_get_data_val(device, channel, index, &aValue) # line 6
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you haven't defined `library_get_data_val` properly, so Cython thinks it's a Python type function you're calling, and doesn't know what to do with the pointer to `aValue`

Try:

```
cdef extern from "header_containing_library_get_data_val.h":
    # I've taken a guess at the signature of library_get_data_val
    # Update it to match reality
    int library_get_data_val(int device, int channel, int index, int* value)
```

That way Cython knows it's a C-function that expects a pointer, and will be happy.

*(Edited to be significantly changed from my original answer, where I misunderstood the problem!)*